# migrar base de datos sqlserver a postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql

Alguien tendrá algún programa para migrar de sqlserver a postgresql? he usado recientemente el ESF Database Migration Toolkit pero lamentablemente es de pago y la demo modifica los campos de la base de datos con una "T" al principio de cada registro. gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola @Alexander. Debes acotar el alcance de tu pregunta. En lugar de pedir por alguna herramienta, puedes solicitar apoyo con la herramienta que estás utilizando para resolver algún problema que tengas como esto de las T en los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza que tal? la solución con esa herramienta seria conseguirse algún crack o la herramienta completa, de lo contrario continuara modificando el valor con T en la versión de prueba. conocerás algún otro método para migrar?